# Inserting legend for two curves with 2 different y-axis-scale, and with its respective y-labels color

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, axis-labels

I hope someone can give me some guidance for the following:

I want to plot two curves that have their own y-axis (left/right), and I want to change the color of the y-label, so that it matches the color of the curve. I have the following code:

```
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(hrbrthemes)
df <- read_csv("TS-ARTICLES.csv")
df <- as.data.frame(df)
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = YEAR)) +
geom_line(aes(y = HEURISTICS), color = "green") +
geom_line(aes(y = HYPERHEURISTICS * 1267/45), color = "blue") +
labs(title = "Time Series of Published Articles", subtitle = "Scopus Search of Heuristics and Hyper-heuristics, accesed at 16 of october 2022", x ="Year", y ="Number of Heuristics Articles") +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 1950, to = 2022, by = 10)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1267), sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . *45/1267, name = "Number of Hyper-heuristics Articles")) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=80, hjust=1), title = element_text(face = "bold"), panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'White', colour = 'black'), panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray"))
print(p1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is just a comment, but the reason why it's so difficult to do this in ggplot is because it's bad practice and leads to misleading graphs (here, for example, it's easy to interpret the blue line to be reaching the same value as the green line in 2020). There are some instances where it works (e.g. a temperature line graph and a histogram of precipitation) but you really should avoid it when the two plots use the same unit (here, counts) and plot type (here, line). Consider faceting, or plotting green line + (% of green which is blue) as bars, or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color for the axis labels could be set via theme options `axis.title.y.left` and `axis.title.y.right`. To add an additional legend move `color=...` inside `aes()`, then use `scale_color_manual` to set the right colors and labels:

Using some fake example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  YEAR = 1950:2022,
  HEURISTICS = seq(0, 1267, length.out = 73),
  HYPERHEURISTICS = seq(0, 40, length.out = 73)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = YEAR)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = HEURISTICS, color = "green")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = HYPERHEURISTICS * 1267 / 45, color = "blue")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(green = "green", blue = "blue"), 
                     labels = c(green = "HEURISTICS", blue = "HYPERHEURISTICS")) +
  labs(
    title = "Time Series of Published Articles",
    subtitle = "Scopus Search of Heuristics and Hyper-heuristics, accesed at 16 of october 2022",
    x = "Year",
    y = "Number of Heuristics Articles"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 1950, to = 2022, by = 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1267), sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 45 / 1267,
    name = "Number of Hyper-heuristics Articles"
  )) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 80, hjust = 1),
    title = element_text(face = "bold"),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "White", colour = "black"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray")
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y.left = element_text(color = "green"),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "blue")
  )
```

[image]